# Immutabality in SpringBoot Pojo

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am aware of the differences b/w immutable vs mutable object.I need to expose REST API and persist customer object into DB.However i have read that objects should be immutable as possible. Now i have below questions:

1. As a spring boot web app when is the object eligible for GC -lets say after a POST request of particular customer
2. What difference does immutability make here as my new update request POST customer would still create a new object anyway ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immutability doesn't change anything to the rules of GC. Immutability has plenty of advantages (simplicity, thread-safety, usability as a key in a Map, cachability, ability to pass an object around without fearing it's modified, etc.), but none of them relates to GC.

An object is eligible to GC when there is no strong reference path from a GC root to that object, whether the object is immutable or not.

If you don't store the customer object created to represent the request body in memory (in a cache, or the session, or something like that), then it's eligible to GC as soon as the request has been handled.